# preprocess request in pretender.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js

there is a a library called pretender.js which allow to mock API, a great tool in general with one limitation: it can't deal with absolute urls. So, when requests are performed by 3rd party libraries and they use an absolute url, like http://localhost:4200/api/v1/s3_mock, there will be an following error `Pretender will not respond to requests for URLs. It is not possible to accurately simluate the browser's CSP. Remove the http://localhost from http://localhost:4200/api/v1/s3_mock and try again`

I wonder how it is possible to alter the request and make url relative inside pretender.

Answer (score 0):

here is a conversation with recipe https://github.com/samselikoff/ember-cli-mirage/issues/192